# Psuedo-Random Variable

Tags: algorithm, random

I have a variable, between 0 and 1, which should dictate the *likelyhood* that a second variable, a random number between 0 and 1, is greater than 0.5. In other words, if I were to generate the second variable 1000 times, the average should be approximately equal to the first variable's value. How do I make this code?

Oh, and the second variable should always be capable of producing either 0 or 1 in any condition, just more or less likely depending on the value of the first variable. Here is a [link to a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p5j1ecmzjp) which models approximately how I would like the program to behave. Each equation represents a separate value for the first variable.

Comment: I've tried something related to x^(1/(2^y)), where x is the first variable and y is the second one. But I'm kind of stuck there, and haven't made much progress in a while.

Comment: What's the likelyhood that you talk about? If var1 is 1, var2 will be greater than 0.5, if var1 is 0, var 2 will not be greater than 0.5?

Comment: Here's a graph representing what i've been trying to work out; https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jf9mnw3yum Each equation represents a different value of the first variable, and the x axis represents the average possible outcome for each value of the first variable.

Comment: Also, why did you delete the part of my question regarding the range of the desired algorithm, simon? People are obviously confused about that aspect of it based on the answer below.

Comment: I am unsure what I am looking at. A pseudo-random number between 0 and 1 has an equal chance of being any number in that range. What you describe in text is that with a value for a of 0.3, you want 70% of the values to be between 0 and 0.5. Because it is pseudo-random, they are equally distributed. 30% of the numbers are equally distributed between 0.5 and 1. You would get 2 straight lines. What your graphs show is that with a=0.3, the chance of getting 0.8 is much lower than the chance of getting 0.9 and that even lower than the chance of getting 1.

Comment: My edit only added the "algorithm" tag and did not delete anything. You may wish to review [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: @Simon http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28134420/revisions Edited during OP's grace period?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not entirely sure what to do with the graph either. But I am 100% sure that it is significant to my problem in some way. I just can't make the necessary logical leap to connect the final pieces. That's why I made a post about it. Also, that inverse transform sampling thing seems interesting.

Comment: I think, but I am not sure, you must find a graph such that the integral (the area under the graph) between 0 and 0.5 is 0.5, the integral between 0 and 1 is 1, and find an x1 and x2 such that the average of x1 and x2 is your variable 1, and the integral between 0 and x1 is 0.25, and the integral between 0 and x2 is 0.75. There is just one problem: There are an infinite amount of x1 and x2 for which this is true. Simon's comment might be helpful in deriving a rng from the graph you find.

Comment: (cont.) I am unsure how to make such a graph. It's too mathematical for me. I am interested in the answer though, so if you find an answer make sure to self-answer your question.

Comment: I'm not too fond of calculus, but I'll try what I might and see what works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable `p` and you are looking for a mapping function `f(x)` that maps random rolls between `x in [0, 1]` to the same interval `[0, 1]` such that the expected value, i.e. the average of all rolls, is `p`.

You have chosen the function prototype

```
f(x) = pow(x, c)
```

where `c` must be chosen appropriately. If `x` is uniformly distributed in `[0, 1]`, the average value is:

```
int(f(x) dx, [0, 1]) == p
```

With the integral:

```
int(pow(x, c) dx) == pow(x, c + 1) / (c + 1) + K
```

one gets:

```
c = 1/p - 1
```

A different approach is to make `p` the median value of the distribution, such that half of the rolls fall below `p`, the other half above `p`. This yields a different distribution. (I am aware that you didn't ask for that.) Now, we have to satisfy the condition:

```
f(0.5) == pow(0.5, c) == p
```

which yields:

```
c = log(p) / log(0.5)
```

With the current function prototype, you cannot satisfy both requirements. Your function is also asymmetric (`f(x, p) != f(1-x, 1-p)`).

Python functions below:

```
def medianrand(p):
    """Random number between 0 and 1 whose median is p"""

    c = math.log(p) / math.log(0.5)
    return math.pow(random.random(), c)

def averagerand(p):
    """Random number between 0 and 1 whose expected value is p"""

    c = 1/p - 1
    return math.pow(random.random(), c)
```

Comment: My god son, you've done it. I don't know exactly how you've done it, but it works flawlessly. Maybe I should study calculus and probability more so that I don't have to make so many stupid SO posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a dummy. First set the first variable to a value between 0 and 1. Then create a random number in the dummy between 0 and 1. If this dummy is bigger than the first variable, you generate a random number between 0 and 0.5, and otherwise you generate a number between 0.5 and 1.

In pseudocode:

```
real a = 0.7
real total = 0.0
for i between 0 and 1000 begin
  real dummy = rand(0,1)
  real b
  if dummy > a then
    b = rand(0,0.5)
  else
    b = rand(0.5,1)
  end if
  total = total + b
end for
real avg = total / 1000
```

Please note that this algorithm will generate average values between 0.25 and 0.75. For a = 1 it will only generate random values between 0.5 and 1, which should average to 0.75. For a=0 it will generate only random numbers between 0 and 0.5, which should average to 0.25.

Comment: The only function of the `yield` keyword that i'm aware of is its use in Python, which incrementally returns items for a lazy iterator. That type of usage doesn't make sense in this context, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean with it here. Also, that seems like a fairly resource intensive way to solve the problem. I was thinking of using exponentiation to modify a normally distributed random number by increasing or decreasing it's value.

Comment: Instead of 1 random number you generate 2. I don't think it should consume -that- many cpu cycles to generate an extra random number. I remember a presentation from a while back where someone showed that truely random rng's in c or c++ took quite a while to set up, but only too 6 or so cpu cycles to get a number. I doubt you can do much better using some mathematical construct. Besides that, how you defined your algorithm it will generate average values between 0.25 and 0.75 for a's between 0 and 1.

Comment: Please reread my main post, I have included some more information regarding how I would like the algorithm to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sort of pseudo-solution to this problem, which I think is acceptable.

Here is the algorithm I made;

```
a = 0.2 # variable one
b = 0 # variable two

b = random.random()
b = b^(1/(2^(4*a-1)))
```

It doesn't actually produce the average results that I wanted, but it's close enough for my purposes.

Edit: [Here's a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3csbmg9jzy) I made that consists of a large amount of datapoints I generated with a python script using this algorithm;

```
import random

mod = 6
div = 100

for z in xrange(div):
    s = 0
    for i in xrange (100000):
        a = (z+1)/float(div) # variable one

        b = random.random() # variable two
        c = b**(1/(2**((mod*a*2)-mod)))
        s += c
    print str((z+1)/float(div)) + "\t" + str(round(s/100000.0, 3))
```

Each point in the table is the result of 100000 randomly generated points from the algorithm; their x positions being the a value given, and their y positions being their average. Ideally they would fit to a straight line of `y = x`, but as you can see they fit closer to an arctan equation. I'm trying to mess around with the algorithm so that the averages fit the line, but I haven't had much luck as of yet.